# .NET MVC3 Html.HiddenFor inside of foreach loop expecting a collection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is a portion of a partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<BLL.DomainModel.Jerk>

@foreach (var jerk in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("AddJerk", "Jerk", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "jerkListForm" }))
    {
     @Html.HiddenFor(jerk => )
       @jerk.Name
       ...  
    }
}
```

The type that the `HiddenFor` lambda is looking for is the same as the `@model` (IEnumerable), whereas I'm looking for a single object within that IEnumerable.

What am I missing?  Why is it still looking for a collection inside of the foreach loop?

Comment: I'm just wondering if you really want the using inside the foreach and not the other way around. That will generate a lot of <form> tags I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All Html For Helpers provided by Asp.Net MVC use the model of the defined model for the page. What you can do is create an `EditorTemplate`. Create a subdirectory in your View folder called `EditorTemplates` such as in `\Home\EditorTemplates\` and add a new view called `Jerk.cshtml` and assign your model that way.

Then you can use the `Html.HiddenFor(f => f.Name)` and so forth for each property. This will give you your typed access that you're expecting.

In your main view you would do the following:

```
@foreach(var jerk in Model) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => jerk)
}
```

or you can call `EditorForModel` where it will automatically loop through and look for the EditorTemplate.

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

The `EditorFor` will look for the EditorTemplate you created first then it will go from there until it either finds an override or it will output one MVC thinks you might need.

Comment: For more detailed help I've written a blog post detailing how to create them: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/

Comment: I'll have a gander.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

```
@model IEnumerable<Type>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item)

}
```

Don't forget that Type must be de/serializable in order for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a for loop instead.  That way your hidden field will have the correct name.  If you use the helpers like in your example, all the hidden fields will have a name of jerk, which won't post back correctly.

```
@foreach (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    var jerk = Model[i];
    using (Html.BeginForm("AddJerk", "Jerk", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "jerkListForm" }))
    {
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i])
       @jerk.Name
       ...  
    }
}
```

If binding doesn't matter to you on the postback, you can simply do

@Html.HiddenFor(jerk => jerk)

Comment: With the for loop I'm getting <input type="hidden" value="BLL.DomainModel.Jerk" name="[3]">  -- I'm really not grasping the utility of HiddenFor().  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ahh, yeah you cannot store the complex object in a hidden field.  You have to store each property or the jerk object.