# Need to replicate Controls for number of days in current month

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a row (TR>) which contains multiple .  In the code below; I will need to replicate controls in the highlighted section below for the number of days in current month. Instead of writing the highlighted section of the code 30 or 31 times manually; is there a better way to get it done?

```
enter code here
```

```
     <tr id="Tr4" style="height:72px" runat="server"> 
        <td valign="top" colspan="1" align="center" class="Employee" width="150" style="display:none"> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" name="lblCounter" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'/> 
         <td valign="top" colspan="1" align="center" class="Employee" width="150" style="display:none"> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblRecordID" name="lblRecordID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RecordID") %>'/> 
        </td> 
     </td> 
        <td valign="top" colspan="1" align="center" class="Employee" width="150" style="display:none"> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeID" name="lblEmployeeID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmployeeID") %>'/> 
        </td> 

     <td valign="top" colspan="1" align="center" class="Employee" width="150"> 
         <asp:Label ID="lblEMployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmployeeName")%>' /> 
     </td>
```

' Columns="1" style="text-align:right"/>

```
         <asp:Label ID="lblHoursWorked2" runat="server" Text='HoursWorked' /> 
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtHoursWorked2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            Text='' Columns="1" style="text-align:right"/> 
            <br /> 

         <asp:Label ID="lblOTMealsPaid" runat="server" Text='Meals Paid'/> 
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtOTMealsPaid2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" 
            Text='<%#Eval("OTMealsPaid") %>' Columns="1" style="text-align:right"/> 

         <br /> 
       </td> 

      </tr> 
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I can't fully remember, but doesn't .net have a Repeater which can be used like a for loop?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

Comment: @WebDevNewbie Yes, it does. There's also a "ListView" control

Answer (score 0):

After some quick searching for looping through HTML in .NET, I came across this in .NET MVC..

```
@foreach (Object in Model)
{ 
    (displays html and data)
}
```

Suppose you could find a way to loop through each day in the current month from a Date object?

EDIT:
[.NET MVC3 Html.HiddenFor inside of foreach loop expecting a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785187/net-mvc3-html-hiddenfor-inside-of-foreach-loop-expecting-a-collection)

It's using a form of looping that you may be able to build off of.. I am not a .NET developer, so I haven't got the setup at my disposal right now to test out a method..

EDIT:
ASP.NET MVC should be similar enough to Java Spring MVC, in which case on your back end, pass a List to your Model with a variable name attached to it, which gets passed to your .NET page (view). On the page within the HTML, you should be able to do something like...

```
@foreach (Date day in dateVariable) {
    <!-- your HTML here -->
}
```

It should go through each element in the list, and paste your html into the page each iteration..

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting me to do.